# Read in data to a ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

First off I know this probably isn't the most sophisticated way to do what I want, but its the way I thought of.

I am attempting to load in Soccer/Football data into an array list then create commands to let me analyze it.

Like if I want to know the last couple fo scores between two teams, or how many goals a team has scored in some seasons.

I have a file (6.txt) with my data delimited by ,

Ex. "12/8/17","Alaves","Las Palmas",2,0,'H',22,6,9,1

I have a contractor that takes in arguments
Then I have an array list for each team with their data

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class games {
    String hTeam;
    String date;
    String aTeam;
    int totGoals;
    int hGoals, aGoals, result, points, wins, draws, losses, hShots, aShots, hShotsTarget, aShotsTarget;

    public games(String date, String hTeam, String aTeam, int hGoals, int aGoals, char result, int hShots, int aShots, int hShotsTarget, int aShotsTarget) {
        this.hTeam = hTeam;
        this.aTeam = aTeam;
        this.hGoals = hGoals;
        this.aGoals = aGoals;
        this.result = result;
        this.hShots = hShots;
        this.aShots = aShots;
        this.date = date;
    }


    public String toString() {
        String temp = "";
        String result = "";
        if (this.result == 'H') {
            result += "won against";
        }
        else if(this.result == 'A') {
            result += "lost to";
        }
        else if (this.result == 'D') {
            result += "drew with";
        }
        temp += "On " + date + " " + hTeam + " " + result + " " + aTeam + " " + hGoals + " to " + aGoals + "\n";
        return temp;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<games> Alaves = new ArrayList<games>();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("6.txt"));
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            Alaves.add(new games(s.nextLine()));
        }



    }

}
```

I want to be able to create an array list for each team with an associated file that will fill that list.

My end goal, is to be able to compare two teams using this data, which team is more likely to win, well lets check head to head matches and goals scored etc.

Comment: Honestly, now might be a good time to learn about either databases, or a data analysis tool like R or maybe Matlab.  Java isn't the best took for the kinds of questions you want to answer.

Comment: What problem are you facing exactly?

Comment: Apologies, the method nextLine() is undefined for type games

Comment: Also yes @TimBiegeleisen I agree, and that was something I was looking into, but I was told to just get some practice with a language I was familiar with and then expand from there as I needed to